# Strange behavior using Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, osgi, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-karaf

I am new to OSGi and it's the first time I am using Apache HttpClient under OSGi.

When I execute this code...

```
try {
        System.out.println("> Creating Method Request");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(baseUri + codec.encode(data));

        System.out.println("> Creating Client");
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        System.out.println("> Use Objects");

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.out.println("> Exception " + ex.getCause());

    } finally {

        System.out.println("> Finally");
    }
```

, I get this behavior: "> Creating Client" gets printed followed by "> Finally". No exception is caught but ">Using Objects" is never print.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an `Error` was thrown rather than an `Exception`? Change the `catch (Exception` to `catch (Throwable` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the Hint. I should also have said that I am an average low java programmer :) Indeed there seems to be a class missing.